# How can I set 'or' in two django model fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

Suppose I have a django model of an Image:

```
from django.db import models
class Image(models.Model):
      ...
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='some_place')
      image_url = models.URLField()
      ...
```

and I want that a user can upload either `image` or its `url` so I can not set both field
`null=True` because I want atleast one of them to show in template. How can I do this?

Comment: Check Django docs for CheckConstraint https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint

Answer (score 1):

You can put `null=True` to both of them and then verify that at least one of the two fields of your form was filled using its `clean` method.

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if not (self.cleaned_data.get('image') or self.cleaned_data.get('image_url')):
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must fill at least one of both fields")
```

If both fields are empty, it will return a validation error saying that at least one of them should be filled.